# How to update ListView in Activity after updating database in other Activity?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;
    private DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private AdapterForNames namesAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforall);
        context = this;

        namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
        mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
        DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }




    public class AdapterForNames extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    AdapterForNames(Context context, ArrayList<String> names){
        super(context,R.layout.settingsname,names);
        this.names = names;
    }

    public void refresh(ArrayList<String> names){
        this.names= names;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater setLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = setLayout.inflate(R.layout.settingsname,parent,false);

        String setItem = names.get(position);
        TextView nameText = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.settingsname);

        nameText.setText(setItem);
        return customView;

    }
}


public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
static String extra = "values";
ListView mListView;
private String name;

final String[] setItems = {"name","birthday","size","sex"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.setuplist);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    context = this;
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    showView();
}

private void showView(){
    DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper= new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from dog where name = ?",new String[]{name});
    //Cursor cursor = db.query("Dog",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String birthday = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("birthday"));
        String size = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("size"));
        String sex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sex"));

        final String[] setValues = {name,birthday,size,sex};
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,setItems,setValues);
        mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String setupItemValue = setValues[position];
                String setupItem = setItems[position];
                Intent intent;
                if(setupItem.equals("name")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeName.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                } else if(setupItem.equals("birthday")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeBirthday.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                }else if(setupItem.equals("size")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeType.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,3);
                }else{
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeSex.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,4);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    cursor.close();
}


private void updateView(){
    DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper= new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("Dog",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String birthday = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("birthday"));
        String size = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("size"));
        String sex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sex"));

        final String[] setValues = {name,birthday,size,sex};
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,setItems,setValues);
        mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String setupItemValue = setValues[position];
                String setupItem = setItems[position];
                Intent intent;
                if(setupItem.equals("name")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeName.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                } else if(setupItem.equals("birthday")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeBirthday.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                }else if(setupItem.equals("size")){
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeType.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,3);
                }else{
                    intent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,ChangeSex.class);
                    intent.putExtra(extra,setupItemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,4);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    cursor.close();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

    DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper= new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("Dog",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("name",data.getStringExtra("return_name"));
                db.update("dog",cv,"id=?",new String[]{"1"});

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("birthday",data.getStringExtra("return_birthday"));
                db.update("dog",cv,"id=?",new String[]{"1"});

            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("size",data.getStringExtra("return_type"));
                db.update("dog",cv,"id=?",new String[]{"1"});
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("sex",data.getStringExtra("return_sex"));
                db.update("dog",cv,"id=?",new String[]{"1"});

            }
            break;

    }
    db.close();
    updateView();
}
```

}

```
   public class DogDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String CREATE_DOG = "create table dog ("
        + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + "name text,"
        + "birthday text,"
        + "size text,"
        + "sex text,"
        + "count integer)";

private Context context;

public DogDatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,"Dog.db",null,1);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DOG);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists Dog");
    onCreate(db);
}


public ArrayList<String> getAllNames(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("Dog",null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            names.add(name);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names;
}
```

}

I can get data from database and I'm able to update data after clicking the name in the `ListView`, but when I return to this `Activity`, I don't know how to update the `ListView`, cause `notifyDataSetChanged()` didn't work.

Have no idea what went wrong, Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you share your adapter code?

Comment: @Ajeet Sure, I just updated my code,please check it again.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Cursor Adapter instead on Array Adapter. Please go through the link. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Comment: u can make static adapter and notify from onther activity

Comment: There's a SimpleCursorAdapter for ListView which notifies and handle the case of database change. Go through google, you will surely get lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and quicker way for you would be to put all this code:

```
DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);

// Edit: to reload all data you must first clear the list
names.clear();

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    // Note: move this out of the bucle to avoid calling it in every iteration
    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in your MainActivity's `onResume()` method, so every time you come back you refresh the data.

**EDIT:** since reloading the data each time the activity calls `onResume`, I would suggest you also use a flag for the MainActivity to know if there have been changes. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (thereWereChanges) {
        realoadDataSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,I tried,but because when I come back to this activity after updating the database,this onResume method will be called again,so onResume method will be excited twice,both  the old data and updated data will  be in the list view.How to delete that old data?

Comment: Reading the DB in `onResume()` does not make much sense. That way you would have to read the DB even if there weren't any changes, for example when you open your app from the background.

Comment: Indeed, but as I stated is the fastest workaround. @Ben if you want to delete the old data you could call `names.clear()`, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` to start your `SetupActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", names.get(position));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SETUP);
    // REQUEST_SETUP is just a private int constant in SettingsActivity
}
```

Override `onActivityResult()` in `SettingsActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_SETUP:
                dataChanged();
                break;

            // other request codes (if any)
        }
    }
}
```

The `dataChanged()` method:

```
private void dataChanged() {
    // fetch the new data from the DB into your ArrayList
    names.clear();
    names.addAll(dbHelper.getAllNames());

    // update the ListView with the new data
    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The `getAllNames()` method in `DogDatabaseHelper`:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllNames() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DOG, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME},
        null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
            names.add(name);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names;
}
```

And finally, when you finished your stuff in `SetupActivity` and inserted/updated the data in the DB, set the result to `RESULT_OK` and return to `SettingsActivity` by calling `finish()`:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

*NOTE:* for better performance, you could pass the ID(s) of the inserted/updated record(s) from `SetupActivity` to `SettingsActivity` in the `Intent`, so instead of querying all rows by calling `getAllNames()`, you could just fetch the modified record(s).